# dynamically add a linear layout in scrollview

Tags: scrollview, android-linearlayout

Actually i am trying to add a linear layout dynamically in a scroll view. I want to treat a linear layout like row and one row contains imageView and TexView so i want to add them dynamically on each call to that function. so it may looks like a listview .. I am tired because of searching every where. please help me

[image]

```
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    >

<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/innerpart"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>



   try{
        //get bitmap image 
         imageview img = new imageview(getAppcontext);
         linear.addview(img);

         // but i want to add image and row in the same row
       }
```

Comment: actually i was trying to create a layout with fixed positions of imageview and textview  so it can able to look like row. and then i want to add that layout where i need to put a row

Comment: I mean, on Stackoverflow it is always better to post some code or markup you already have written

Comment: i am new on this site kindly tell me how can i upload a picture so that i can easily display a picture what exactly i want i am new  on android

Comment: i have added some code

Comment: in the edit window, you can press `Cntrl-G` and upload a picture

Comment: sir  Sebastian Godelet http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ii8zus&s=6 this is what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are here so you can dynamically add LinerLayout to ScrollView:

```
for loop {
    LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(context, attrs //layout position params);
    ImageView newIV = new ImageView(context, attrs);
    TextView newTV = new TextView(context, attrs);
    newLL.addView(newIV);
    newLL.addView(newTV);

    yourScrollView.add(newLL);
}
```

Here your asked style, looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"      
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView     
        android:id="@+id/list_image"   
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of Song-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

<!-- Rightend Duration -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="5:45"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->    
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can we add imageview and textView inside it at fixed positions ?

Comment: Example: new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER) you can create for each layout params and set its to imageView and textView

Comment: can you suggest me how to create this layout ? http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ii8zus&s=6

Comment: See this url, here more have styles: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html